# What default fonts are installed on Azure Web Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I'm using SelectPdf to render PDF's on my Azure Web App, and it turns out that the Azure sandboxing model means that custom web fonts (OTF, TTF, etc) cannot be embedded in PDF's.  Apparently the issue is the same for other PDF generation tools.

Microsoft have confirmed they are not currently fixing the issue but have it in their future plans:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/32622797-support-custom-web-fonts-in-azure-app-services

I'd like to know what fonts are already installed on Azure Web Apps that would be available for use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is the standard Windows fonts list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use Windows Containers on App Service which has no sandbox limitation since the Web App runs in a Hyper-V Container.

Here you can follow the quickstart to run a Windows Container in App Service:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container

This is a custom font example for App Service using Windows Containers
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/custom-font-win-container/